# How i can access the Registration process inside my asp.net core MVC

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have created an asp.net MVC core web application which uses individual accounts, as follow:-
[image]

where i got a predefined Register and login logic (actions methods and Views), but i can not access the related controller classes and views,, so is it possible to access and modify the built-in registration and logging logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- From Solution Explorer, right-click on the project > Add > New Scaffolded Item.
- From the left pane of the Add Scaffold dialog, select Identity > ADD.
- In the ADD Identity dialog, select the options you want.

  - Select your existing layout page, or your layout file will be overwritten with incorrect markup. For example ~/Pages/Shared/_Layout.cshtml for Razor Pages ~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml for MVC projects
  - Select the + button to create a new Data context class.
- Select ADD.

See more details in [Scaffold identity into an empty project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#scaffold-identity-into-an-empty-project)

Comment: ok i did so and i am able to access the Identity business logic thanks a lot. but i have a question, let say i update some of the business logic for the register and login inside the built-in Identity, and then in the future i update the asp.net core Identity,, will my customization got lost?

Comment: If you will update the identity it could break your changes, but in general MS always releases a step-by-step migration guides to help upgrade from lower to higher framework versions. This is the case for any customized service, you have to manually do migration steps to guarantee smooth upgrade. Meanwhile, during the past time there was only minor changes to the identity related to the .net core framework version and not real update to the default identity system.